# Regex: select between mathced brackets : templating engine

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I was playing with PHP today creating a small language (just for fun), but I encountered a problem:

**How can I select between matching brackets?**

My template string:

```
for(items as item){ // this bracket
  if(some_condition){
      // do stuff

  } // my regex stops here


} // and this bracket
```

I used [this regex](http://www.regexr.com/39epn) `[\w]+\([ \w]+\){([\s\n\r\t/\w(){}]+?)}`, but it stop when finds the first closed bracket.

**How can I make it select everything between his matching brackets?:**

for(items as item){  // this bracket

```
if(some_condition){
      // do stuff

  } // my regex stops here
```

}  // and this bracket

Then I will compile what's in the `for` separately.

PS: Please don't post comments like "don't bother doing this" or "don't reinvent the wheel". It is just for learning purposes.

Comment: I want top match everything between matching brackets. the code inside doesn't matter;

Comment: OMG.. stop editing that code. the `for` was put out so you can see what I want to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [recursion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php):

```
$code = '
for(items as item) {
    if(some_condition) {
        while stuff {
            hi
        }
    }
    done
}
';

$re = '/{ ( ( [^{}] | (?R) ) * ) }/x';

preg_match_all($re, $code, $m);
print_r($m[1][0]);
```

This prints

```
if(some_condition) {
    while stuff {
        hi
    }
}
done
```

that is, the inner block has been detected correctly.

That said, regular expressions is a wrong tool for *parsing* formal languages (they are fine for *tokenizing* though). For example, the above will break hopelessly once you add a string literal containing "{":

```
for(items as item){
    echo "hi there :{ ";
}
```

What you actually need is a parser, either crafted manually (good learning exercise!) or generated (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720362/what-is-a-good-parser-generator-for-php) for options).

Comment: I think you are right. that echo is a very good example to not use regex. I'll build my own parser (I don't really like to use 'generated ' stuff from internet.I like to build my own stuff).Thank you very much for your examples and ides.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex which allows another `}` bracket to be matched.

```
[\w]+\([ \w]+\){([\s\n\r\t\/\w(){}]+?}[\s\n\r\t\/\w(){}]+?)}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qW4dI6/1)

Comment: this brakes if there are more instructions in my brackets.I can't do that for every instruction.

Comment: @boyd how about this http://regex101.com/r/qW4dI6/2 ? It works for all the cases..

Comment: I spent 1 hour to understand that lookahead thing and yes it works how I describe it in my question. Good Job. Tho how can I make it match when I have some other code at the end like `print variable; exit program;`? .It doesn't work if I add an extra space at the end

Comment: yep. Because of line end `$` anchor. Post your input on the demo site and provide the saved link here. I will try to solve your problem... or get into the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/mC4iG8/2.  how can I select that 'FORs' and also keep the code after that?

Comment: did you want to match the first two for's?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60691/discussion-between-boyd-and-avinash-raj).